# Why was one of the Roshan drops made to be "Cheese"?

Tags: dota-2

I've always wondered why the item that drops after killing Roshan three times was made to be Cheese. Is it known if this is some sort of inside joke among the game developers, a reference to the original Dota or another game, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There happened to be a cheese item icon in Warcraft 3, so Icefrog and company used it for the item .

Here are the patch notes where it was introduced: 
[Dota 638 released](http://borkweb.com/story/dota-638-released)